# Finding the exact sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n(\pi)^{2n}}{4^n(2n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The solution says that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n(\pi)^{2n}}{4^n(2n)!} = 0$. I only know how to prove this converges. What can I use to calculate the sum or where should I start?

Comment: Hint: Compare the pattern to Taylor of some trigonometric functions.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{(\pi)^{2n}}{4^n}=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n(\pi)^{2n}}{4^n(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n(\pi/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
then use 
$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^n(x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is simply $\cos(\pi/2)$, since
$$\cos(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=e^x+e^{-x}$$

Here $x=\dfrac{i\pi}2$